# Can't write stream to SBT process on Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse-plugin, sbt, inputstream, outputstream

I'm now working on a SBT eclipse plugin which provides a graphical interface to run SBT task on Eclipse, like Ant view.

Generally speaking, I do this by starting a new SBT process, and redirect its `OutputStream` to Eclipse console view, and write to its `InputStream` to run tasks.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java",
        "-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m",
        "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m",
        "-Dsbt.log.noformat=true", "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m",
        "-jar", getSbtLaunchPath()).directory(new File(path));
processBuilder.environment().put("JAVA_HOME", getJavaHome());
Process sbtProcess = processBuilder.start();
final InputStream inStream = sbtProcess.getInputStream();
(new thread to write the inputStream to eclipse console view)

OutputStream outStream = sbtProcess.getOutputStream();  
PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(outStream);   //the writer to write command to SBT process
```

In this way, if I want to run `compile` task, I just do like this:

```
pWriter.println("compile")
```

All things work well on Mac. But when I test it on Windows, the `PrintWriter` can't write to SBT process as supposed.

To this issue, what I am sure is that:

- The SBT process runs.
- `PrintWriter` can write to a small Java echo program process under the same circumstance, which means the SBT process may be different from a normal Java Process in some part.

What I suspect is that:

- There is an encoding-dismatch problem on Windows, making SBT process can't recognise the line terminator, so that SBT doesn't know it's a command input.
- SBT contributors did some magical trick in Windows system, making the same thing working well on Mac doesn't work on Windows.

So, I think it's time to ask you guys. What do you think of this issue? Do I miss something?

Comment: Possibly related to this? - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/871

Comment: @EugeneYokota I am wondering if SBT reads STDIN on a Windows cmd? According to my boss, Windows cmd and Linux bash seem to use different mechanisms in process the command. For example, you enter `echo compile|sbt` in cmd, it just starts SBT then don't compile, but in bash, with the same command, it will starts SBT then do compile task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on the jline library used by SBT.

I solved this problem by passing `-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal` to java options.